# Semantic UI popup with ui checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I am trying to trigger a semantic ui popup on a ui checkbox onChecked event but it doesn't work the way it is supposed to. I am obviously new to Semantic UI. The code I've written shows a popup on hover but I thought the onChecked event would override the hover state. The popup now appears on hover after the onChecked event. Any ideas how to get this working?

I am using JQuery with Semantic UI JS and CSS versions:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.js
```

Here is my code

HTML

```
<!-- UI Checkbox -->
<div class="ui checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="popUpCheckBox">
  <label>PopUp Checkbox</label>
</div>

<!-- PopUp DIV -->
<div class="ui flowing popup">
  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        Column 1
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column 2
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column 3
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".ui.checkbox").checkbox({
  onChecked() {
    $(".checkbox").popup({
      popup: $(".flowing.popup"),
      position: "bottom center"
    });
  },
  onUnchecked() {
    $(".flowing.popup").remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a popup option called `on` that you can set to `"manual"` to prevent the popup from showing on hover:

```
$(".ui.checkbox").checkbox({
  onChecked() {
    $(".checkbox").popup({
      popup: $(".flowing.popup"),
      position: "bottom center",
      on: "manual"  //the default is "hover"
    });
    $(".checkbox").popup("show");  //show the popup manually
  },
  onUnchecked() {
    $(".flowing.popup").remove();
  }
});
```

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0GwhfmiXbYoYxue6?open=lib%2Fscript.js